# How to get receipt-data from Post request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to send a `receipt` to my `Node.js server`. At the moment It prints out the `receipt-data` in firebase which indicates its gotten it from the `POST` request I sent from my `iOS App`. However i can't pass properly in my code to be validated in `const receipt = request.body;`. How can I pass it along in the correct way?. Thanks.

```
exports.receiptValidation = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    const receipt = request.body;
    console.log(receipt);

    iap.config({
        applePassword: 'MySharedAppleKey',
        test: true
    });

    iap.setup((error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Failed to validate receipt', error);
        }
       });

    iap.validate(receipt).then((pResponse) => {
            //Check if receipt is valid
            if (iap.isValidated(pResponse)) {
                console.log('The receipt is valid', pResponse);
                response.send(pResponse);
            }
            return pResponse;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(`Sorry couldn't validate receipt`, error);
            response.send(error);
            return error
        });
});
```

Here is my output in Firebase. I'm using a `firebase function`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing my receipt-data string in both `Swift` and `Server code`

Swift

```
let receiptData = receipt!.base64EncodedString()
let requestReceiptDict = ["receipt": receiptData]
```

Node.js

```
const receipt = request.body.receipt;
console.log(receipt);
```